# Eigen problems with gazebo

Tags: gazebo, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to simulate the PR2 in gazebo.  I'm running ubuntu 10.4, 32-bit.  I have both diamondback and electric on my machine (another post leads me to believe that this may cause eigen problems if I use the wrong one).  I keep getting the crash below related to eigen.

If it is a diamondback vs. electric problem, how do I get rid of one.  "rm -rf" doesn't work.

ScopedName[pr2]
[ INFO] [1315876045.110793136, 377.204000000]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin artifically sets minimum intensity to 101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
gazebo: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 7595, exit code -6].
log files: /home/pyanik/.ros/log/9e36f242-dda4-11e0-90fc-0026c7674548/gazebo-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11187/eigen-problems-with-gazebo/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

might be the [same issue here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2135/gazebo-headless-crashes-when-starting-pr2launch), see [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5164), patched in [trunk](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/37898).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1